# How can I retrieve a collection of values from nested HTML-like elements using RegExp?

Tags: html, regex, parsing

I have a problem creating a regular expression for the following task:

Suppose we have HTML-like text of the kind:

```
<x>...<y>a</y>...<y>b</y>...</x>
```

I want to get a collection of values inside `<y></y>` tags located inside a given `<x>` tag, so the result of the above example would be a collection of two elements ["a","b"].

Additionally, we know that:

- `<y>` tags cannot be enclosed in other `<y>` tags
- `...` can include any text or other tags.

How can I achieve this with RegExp?

Answer (score 9):

This is a job for an [HTML/XML parser](http://htmlparsing.icenine.ca/).  You *could* do it with regular expressions, but it would be very messy.  There are examples in the page I linked to.

Comment: unfortunately, the text is not guaranteed to be valid XML nor it is in HTML format

Comment: Well assuming it is HTML, the standard answer is to run it through Tidy. With --clean, Tidy outputs only valid XHTML that should be parsable by virtually any HTML/XML package.

Comment: +1 this - why does everyone want to parse XML with regex's these days?

Comment: First, as I said - this is not XML. Second, I don't want to be involved into processing this text with any tools to convert it to good HTML/XML only to be able to parse it with standard HTML/XML libs. This is overhead. The text I'm talking about is small & simple. RegEx is exactly what matches here.

Comment: Processing and parsing are going to be way simpler than a regular expression when you have an unlimited number of potential matches.  Try out the tools that were designed for this problem before you create even more problems for yourself.

Comment: +1 for not falling for the common misuse of regular expressions that is parsing nested structures

Comment: I can recommend Beautiful Soup for Python. Perfect for parsing invalid HTML/XML-ish data.

Answer (score 3):

I'm taking your word on this:

```
"y" tags cannot be enclosed in other "y" tags

input looks like: <x>...<y>a</y>...<y>b</y>...</x>
```

and the fact that everything else is also *not* nested and correctly formatted. (Disclaimer: If it is not, it's not my fault.)

First, find the contents of any X tags with a loop over the matches of this:

```
<x[^>]*>(.*?)</x>
```

Then (in the loop body) find any Y tags within match group 1 of the "outer" match from above:

```
<y[^>]*>(.*?)</y>
```

Pseudo-code:

```
input = "<x>...<y>a</y>...<y>b</y>...</x>"
x_re  = "<x[^>]*>(.*?)</x>"
y_re  = "<y[^>]*>(.*?)</y>"

for each x_match in input.match_all(x_re)
  for each y_match in x_match.group(1).value.match_all(y_re)
    print y_match.group(1).value
  next y_match
next x_match
```

Pseudo-output:

```
a
b
```

---

Further clarification in the comments revealed that there is an arbitrary amount of Y elements within any X element. This means there can be no single regex that matches them *and* extracts their contents.

Comment: thanks. Didn't mention it from the start, but I do understand how to achieve the goal using loops. But I'm 100% sure there's a solution that uses single "match" operation - and that's what I'm trying to figure out :)

Comment: If there is no hard limit on the number of Y elements, then is no regex only solution. What makes you so sure there is? Maybe the question is missing more details.

Comment: As I said, your question is missing some details on the exact structure of the strings you expect to be dealing with.

Comment: there's no limit on number of "y" tags (hence no limit on resulting collection size). what other details do you think I need to provide?

Comment: nesting or no nesting, elements can have attributes or not, is it machine generated or user input, and last but not least: what are you *really* trying to do? Maybe there are better ways than regex to get you there.

Comment: "y" cannot be nested within another "y", but it can be nested within some other tag, say "z"; machine-generated non-valid HTML (HTML-like) that I cannot control; lets put it like this - currently i would like to know if it is possible to do the task with single regexp match

Comment: and attributes are possible inside any tag (incl "x" and "y")

Comment: Okay, I see. If you want to get hold of the textual content of the Y tags, you won't be able to do it with a single regex, period. This is not the way regular expressions work. Use a loop as indicated, I'll expand my regex to accommodate the attributes.

Comment: with subpattern subgroup matches this should work, but this is dependent to language, because not all languages support that regex feature.

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple: Use XPath :)

Comment: He said in a comment to @Bill the Lizard that "text is not guaranteed to be valid XML"

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we knew what language or tool you're using; there's a great deal of variation in syntax, semantics, and capabilities.  Here's one way to do it in Java:

```
String str = "<y>c</y>...<x>...<y>a</y>...<y>b</y>...</x>...<y>d</y>";
String regex = "<y[^>]*+>(?=(?:[^<]++|<(?!/?+x\\b))*+</x>)(.*?)</y>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
while (m.find())
{
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Once I've matched a `<y>`, I use a lookahead to affirm that there's a `</x>` somewhere up ahead, but there's no `<x>` between the current position and it.  Assuming the pseudo-HTML is reasonably well-formed, that means the current match position is inside an "x" element.

I used possessive quantifiers heavily because they make things like this so much easier, but as you can see, the regex is still a bit of a monster.  Aside from Java, the only regex flavors I know of that support possessive quantifiers are PHP and the JGS tools (RegexBuddy/PowerGrep/EditPad Pro).  On the other hand, many languages provide a way to get all of the matches at once, but in Java I had to code my own loop for that.

So it *is* possible to do this job with one regex, but a very complicated one, and both the regex and the enclosing code have to be tailored to the language you're working in.